# google earth like UI android

Tags: android

I want to use google earth on Android App, because the motion is really smooth and the attractiveness of the UI. Is there any framework or controls or APIs available for integrating google earth like UI in android apps.

I want to display a particular location
I want to zoom in/out to locations
I want to add/display markers from a particular zoom level onwards.

Hope I described my problem well. If it is not clear I will explain more.

Please give me answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there isn't anything quite like Google Earth (mostly because Google doesn't offer Earth for Android), the Maps API offers the same functionality you're looking for. From what I remember of the last time I compared Maps to Earth, the only reason you'd pick Earth over Maps is if you wanted a 3-D spherical projection of the Earth at the lowest zoom levels.

Using the Google Maps API is fairly simple. Follow these steps.

1. [Sign up for an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup).
2. [Use your SDK Manager to download the Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing).
3. ???
4. Profit!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to implement earth instead of maps due to its 3-d spherical projection..

Comment: Then I don't think there's an option for you (at least not yet). Earth is already graphics-intensive on some older computers, I doubt the Google team plans on porting Earth to Android until mobile tech gets more advanced.